# Blinking Background color in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, tags

I am trying to have a blinking background color between Red and Wite by writing 2 functions with 3milli-seconds interval, but unfortunately, it doesnt work with my set element class named, "Bad".

Can someone help me what am I doing wrong?

Code is below:

```
function badBG(){
    var colors = ['Red','White']
        for(i=0; i<2; i++){
            colorBG = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
            // console.log(colorBG)
        }
        
        return colorBG 
}

function blinkBG(){
    blink = badBG()
    document.getElementsByClassName('Bad').style.backgroundColor = blink;
}


setInterval("blinkBG()",300);
```

All are straight to the point functions and css methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use a CSS animation:

```css
.bad{
  padding:30px;
  animation: blink 300ms infinite;
}

@keyframes blink{
  from {
    background: white;
  }
  to{
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bad">I'm very bad</div>
```

Comment: it's not allowed to ask for upvotes or answers to be checked. Especially mentioning that you upvotes the question and expect  an upvote in return is a punishable infrictaion

Comment: @tacoshy noted, just teaching a new comer how stackoverflow works. otherwise it's demotivating for every responder when a new comer doesn't accept a proper answer

Comment: @tacoshy i don't do that for established users

Comment: that's also how SO works getting sometimes no crdit for the time effort. As I said, this still does not justify a breaking of rules

Comment: @tacoshy could you help to find this policy in the SO help? no luck

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403392/is-it-ok-to-leave-a-comment-asking-for-upvotes

Answer (score 0):

While I would recommend solely solving this on the CSS level as Alexander Nenashev showed, there is also a clean JavaScript solution to it.

You simply us `setInterval` in combination with `classList.toggle()` to toggle a class in CSS. Means by adding/removing it:

```js
const BAD = document.querySelectorAll('.bad');

BAD.forEach(element => {
  setInterval(function() {
    element.classList.toggle('bg-red');
  }, 300)
})
```

```css
.bad{
  padding:30px;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bad">I'm very bad</div>
```